# kdb - Nice way of ordering symbols

Tags: kdb

I have a kdb table containing future data, with the months to contract expiry are stored as symbols like `` `M0`M1`M2... `` etc. I want to order this based on expiry to get a list like ``` `M1``M2`M3 ``` etc but when I use asc I get `` `M1`M11`M12...`M2`21... `` etc. I suppose one way to achieve my goal, is to strip of the M cast to integer, sort and then recast back to string, add the M back, and then cast to symbol. But this seems like a long winded way. I was just wondering if there was a better approach?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have replicated a simple version of your problem with:

```
q)t:([] a:`a`b`c`d`e`f; b:`M1`M4`M2`M21`M12`M11)
q)`num xasc update num: "I"$1_'string b from t
a b   num
---------
a M1  1
c M2  2
b M4  4
f M11 11
e M12 12
d M21 21
```

I just made a new column which extracts the integer of `b` and ascends the table using this column.  You would then be able to delete this column as well if you like using something like

```
delete num from `num xasc update num: "I"$1_'string b from t
```

to return your desired table.

Note: this solution assumes that the form of the months to expiry column is always `M(months)`

A more concise method could be converting `b` to bytes with `-8!` by using something like:

```
q)`num xasc update num:-8!'b from t
a b   num
----------------------------------
a M1  0x010000000c000000f54d3100
c M2  0x010000000c000000f54d3200
b M4  0x010000000c000000f54d3400
f M11 0x010000000d000000f54d313100
e M12 0x010000000d000000f54d313200
d M21 0x010000000d000000f54d323100
```

but this method would be just a bit slower.

Comment: If needed, you could cut out the additional column with ```t iasc"I"$1_'string t`b```

Comment: Or use your good idea on the byte conversion! ```t iasc -8!'t`b```